# Tried several methods but this Value Error keeps popping up running with the WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, valueerror

Below is the part where my code program meets a runtime ValueError.

```py
while real_original_amount > 1:
    future_amount=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="app"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/span/span')
    future_amount_float = float(future_amount.text)
    betting_count = ()
```

As I'm using selenium as part of the program, im taking webelements into a variable then convert the variable to a float number as it is on the website. Below is the error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Selenium Projects\main.py", line 74, in <module>
    future_amount_float = float(future_amount.text)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

Tried several different methods to solve this ValueError but all didn't really worked out.

Comment: What does `print(future_amount.text)` give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

...implies that the variable `' '` cannot be converted to *float* as it is a *blank*.

---

### Solution

Possibly the `textContext` wasn't rendered when the line of code was executed. So to locate the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  future_amount = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//[@id="app"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/span/span")))
  future_amount_float = float(future_amount.text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```